# vb6 custome application setup.exe run on windows7 gives "An error occureed while registering the file 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'"

Tags: windows, dll, vb6, installation

I have written multiple applications in VB6 that we send to customers for my companies product configuration in the field.
    I use the package and deployment wizard in VB6 SP6
    When customers in the field run the setup.exe, they get the error-

> An error occurred while registering the file 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll'

This happens for many files - such as Ws32_32.dll, setupapi.dll, mswinsck.ocx...

I have read that this has to do with SysWOW64 having pre-compiled drivers in it that are an older revision than VB6 has access to, and that the vb6 setup.exe that is part of the package cannot update the SysWOW64 drivers.

Is there a way to make a VB6 package that installs on Windows 7?  If not is there at least a way to suppress the errors so that customers do not see them, the application does run.

Comment: Ws32_32/hid.dll are system libraries, your setup application should not be attempting to install them or register them (they cannot infact be registered as they are not COM libraries at all)

Comment: The PDW was always fairly terrible, use something else that gives you more control E.g. http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb

Comment: You are either packaging DLLs you shouldn't be or you have a nasty malware infestation.  You should not be deploying device drivers at all except in extremely rare cases.  Not using the PDW won't fix a thing, in fact having trouble with it suggests you should not be using VB6 at all.  This is a tool for professional programmers, that's why Microsoft dropped the Standard Edition after VB5.  VB.Net is the tool for kids.

Comment: Maybe provide an example, what dependencies are checked in the PDW? As some of the other comments state, you may just have too many dependencies checked.  Ultimately, @AlexK. suggestion may be for the best.